# How does the latexrevise command actually work?

Tags: latexdiff, changes, trackchanges

I am following the example given in the documentation of [latexdiff](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/support/latexdiff/doc/latexdiff-man.pdf).

I run the following code and get a third latex file with the changes.

```
latexdiff  example-draft.tex example-rev.tex > example-diff.tex
```

Next, I edit the `example-diff.tex` file and keep some of the original writing and save the file.

Finally, the documentation says to run the following command to accept the changes

```
latexrevise -a example-rev.tex > example-final.tex
```

My question is, in this final command, there is no mention of the `example-diff.tex` file which I edited, so how does `latexrevise`
know which changes to accept if `example-diff.tex` is not mentioned in the command line?

Comment: I am afraid this is a documentation bug. It should have read `latexrevise -a example-diff.tex > example-final.tex` .  (the documentation will be corrected accordingly in the next release)